# Inserir dados do v-for em class css no VueJs2

Tags: css, vue.js-2

```
<template v-for="d in data" >
     <a :key="d.id" class="zone{{d.value}}" href="{{d.code}}" >{{d.name}}</a>
</template>
```

Este exemplo simplesmente não funciona, como eu posso passar os valores que então dentro de "d" para o atributos? Como resolvo esse impasse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem a dúvida, porém creio que o problema é na maneira que você está utilizando a interpolação.

A interpolação "{{}}" é utilizada apenas entre as tags, e não dentro delas, referenciando suas variáveis que estão dentro de `computed` ou de seu `data ()`.

No caso, em uma tag dentro de um atributo **não** é utilizado a interpolação, e sim o [v-bind:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) ou os dois pontos ":", que é exatamente igual ao v-bind, porém em uma forma mais curta de utilizá-lo.

Seu código no caso creio eu que ficaria assim:

```
<template v-for="d in data" >
     <a :key="d.id" class="zone" :class="d.value" :href="d.code" >{{ d.name }}</a>
</template>
```

Só não entendi muito bem o que você quis fazer exatamente no caso do atributo `class`, portanto presumi que a classe `zone` é estática, e o `d.value` será outra classe dinâmica, mediante ao valor da variável.

Neste caso não tem problema de ter dois atributos class em uma tag, o Vuejs irá realizar um merge de todas as classes automaticamente, das dinâmicas com as estáticas.

Comment: Era exatamente isso minha dúvida, meu erro era que eu não estava usando o v-bind. Quanto a _class_, era pra resultar em tipo **class="zone1"** mas vi que também pode ser usando assim **:class="'zone'+d.value"**. gostei da dica do agrupamento de classes, isso vai ser muito útil.

Comment: Uma outra coisa que reparei agora, o `:key` que você está colocando na tag `<a>` provavelmente está incorreto. Ele é para ser utilizado na mesma tag do `v-for`. No caso, como o `v-for` é um template você não vai conseguir utilizá-lo, assim pode até mesmo remover da tag `<a>`, mas se fosse em uma `<div>` por exemplo, é aconselhável a por mesmo, mas aí você coloca na própria `<div>` que está realizando o `v-for`.

Comment: Na verdade, esta :key só esta ai por exigência do próprio vuejs2. o eslint-plugin-vue reclama que agora é recomendado o uso do v-bind:key ao fazer laços com v-for, porem se eu retirar, o código funciona do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Então, mas o que eu tava querendo dizer é que tem mesmo, só que tem que ser na mesma tag do v-for, e não as de dentro dela.. mas ok.